# Bootstrap multiselect dropdown inside uncollapsed panel is cut off

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a collapsible accordion panel that is expanded with a single bootstrap multiselect dropdown box.  It has many options.  The expanded accordion panel opens to show the dropdown box but cuts off the options underneath it.  I have tried adjusting the `z-index` in css but that didn't work.

Here is the code:

```html
<div class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Category provided by the borrower for the loan request.</p>
        <select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="purpose">
            <option value="car">car</option>
            <option value="credit card">credit card</option>
            <option value="debt consolidation">debt consolidation</option>
            <option value="educational">educational</option>
            <option value="home improvement">home improvement</option>
            <option value="house">house</option>
            <option value="major purchase">major purchase</option>
            <option value="medical">medical</option>
            <option value="moving">moving</option>
            <option value="other">other</option>
            <option value="renewable energy">renewable energy</option>
            <option value="small business">small business</option>
            <option value="vacation">vacation</option>
            <option value="wedding">wedding</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Can you post the other part of your code too ? Maybe in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the way accordion content is presented.  It doesn't do so hot with [dynamic content](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2274).

In order to [prevent it from truncating content](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7742), you can set `overflow: visisble`:

```css
.panel-group .panel {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/eo4x3gsj/)